# Make implicit rule fails at first time but succeeds at second time

Tags: makefile

I encounter an error relating to implicit rule in `make` (3.81). The example codes are:

```
dongli:test02 dongli$ ls -R
Makefile a.F90    b.F90    dir

./dir:
a.t.F90
```

The dependencies among the codes are:

```
a.t.F90: a.F90
a.t.o: a.t.F90
b.o: b.F90
b: a.t.o b.o
```

That is `a.F90` is intermediate code, and `a.t.F90` will be updated when `a.F90` is updated. My `make` process is:

**Test 1** (All codes on position):

```
-------------------------------------------------------------
 Project: >>> test <<<
-------------------------------------------------------------
 Creating dependency a.t.o
-------------------------------------------------------------
-----> ./dir/a.t.F90
 Creating dependency b.o
-------------------------------------------------------------
-----> b.F90
 Creating target 'b'
 ---> b is created.
-------------------------------------------------------------
 Finished
-------------------------------------------------------------
```

**Test 2** (touch `a.F90`):

```
dongli:test02 dongli$ touch a.F90
dongli:test02 dongli$ make
-------------------------------------------------------------
 Project: >>> test <<<
-------------------------------------------------------------
 Processing templates in a.F90
-------------------------------------------------------------
 Creating dependency a.t.o
-------------------------------------------------------------
-----> a.t.F90
gfortran: error: a.t.F90: No such file or directory
gfortran: fatal error: no input files
compilation terminated.
make: *** [a.t.o] Error 1
```

**Test 3**: (Run `make` again):

```
dongli:test02 dongli$ make
-------------------------------------------------------------
 Project: >>> test <<<
-------------------------------------------------------------
 Creating dependency a.t.o
-------------------------------------------------------------
-----> ./dir/a.t.F90
 Creating dependency b.o
-------------------------------------------------------------
-----> b.F90
 Creating target 'b'
 ---> b is created.
-------------------------------------------------------------
 Finished
-------------------------------------------------------------
```

I know there is a bug in `make` about **directory caching** (see [here](http://savannah.gnu.org/bugs/?func=detailitem&item_id=15583)), but in my case, `dir/a.t.F90` exists all the time. Any idea? Thanks!

**Update1:**

I use `make -d` to capture the following information in test 2:

```
       Finished prerequisites of target file `a.t.F90'.
       Prerequisite `a.F90' is newer than target `a.t.F90'.
      Must remake target `a.t.F90'.
  Ignoring VPATH name `./dir/a.t.F90'.

  ...

        Successfully remade target file `a.t.F90'.
 Finished prerequisites of target file `a.t.o'.
 Prerequisite `a.t.F90' of target `a.t.o' does not exist.
Must remake target `a.t.o'.
```

Why `./dir/a.t.F90` is ignored when its prerequisite `a.F90` is newer than it?

**Update2:**

I have put the example codes on [gist](https://gist.github.com/dongli/6059091).

**Update3:**

I found the following relating information:

> If a target needs to be rebuilt, GNU make discards the file name found
>   during the VPATH search for this target, and builds the file locally
>   using the file name given in the makefile. If a target does not need
>   to be rebuilt, GNU make uses the file name found during the VPATH
>   search.

Comment: I have isolated this error into a minimal set. If anyone needs them to figure out what is wrong, I can put them somewhere.

Comment: Thanks, this was exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I make a workaround that I inserted some scripts in the implicit rule that add the missing directory part of the code, since `VPATH` has some constraints on this.

```
%.o: %.$(1)
    @echo " Creating dependency $$@"
    @echo $$(seperator)
    @TEMPLATE_PATTERN='.*\.t\.$(1)'; \                                           <
     if [[ $$$$(dirname $$<) == '.' && '$$<' =~ $$$$TEMPLATE_PATTERN ]]; then \  <
         SRC=$(PROJECT_ROOT)/.codemate/processed_codes/$$<; \                    <
     else \                                                                      <
         SRC=$$<; \                                                              <
     fi; \                                                                       <
     $(FC) -c $$$$SRC $(OPTIONS) $(FFLAGS) $(INCLUDES)
```

labeled by `<`.

Answer (score 2):

You really need to show the rules that create these targets.  You've provided a lot of information about many aspects of your build, but one of the most critical aspects of debugging make issues is seeing the rules.

Failures like this (where the first build fails and the second succeeds) are almost invariably due to rules that do not behave as you have described them to make.  If you tell make that a rule builds a file "foo", by creating something like `foo : bar`, but then the recipe that you write doesn't actually create "foo" but rather "bar/foo", something like:

```
foo : bar ; cp bar bar/foo
```

then that is wrong.  Another common reason for such issues is that you define a rule that builds "foo.x", but it also builds "foo.y" and you don't tell make about it but then later use "foo.y" as a prerequisite, that can't work.  You have to define a rule that tells make that both those files are generated from a single invocation of the recipe, such as:

```
%.x %.y : %.z ; cp $< $*.x && cp $< $*.y
```

And finally, you mention VPATH above and it looks like you're trying to use VPATH to find generated files.  That will not work.  VPATH can *only* be used to find source files (files make doesn't know how to build and expects to always be present).  Without seeing more about your makefiles and how the rules are constructed, that's about all we can say.

Edited to add:

I'm not sure it's really necessary to use so much eval and call here; often people seem to go straight to these very powerful tools when simpler ones would suffice just as well.  In any event, the problem you're having is exactly as I suspected in my first comment above; you have this rule:

```
%.t.F90: %.$(1)
        @echo " Processing templates in $$^"
        @echo $$(seperator)
        @cp $$< dir/$$@
```

Note the last line, where instead of creating `$@` you're creating `dir/$@`; this is precisely the situation I described above.  Whenever you have a rule that builds something that is not exactly `$@`, it's almost 100% certain that rule is wrong.  You need to write this as:

```
dir/%.t.F90: %.$(1)
        @echo " Processing templates in $$^"
        @echo $$(seperator)
        @cp $$< $$@
```

and maybe more changes to match that target.

Comment: Thanks for helping! I have put the code on the gist https://gist.github.com/dongli/6059091.